# How to send the CSRF token to the client when using synchronizer token pattern?

Tags: security, token, csrf

In the synchronizer token pattern, the server generates a random token and this token has to be submitted by each form submission by the client. How can the client get to know the CSRF token that was created in the server?

Answer (score 2):

Upon GET requests, you can put the token into the resulting page. It can either be written in forms as a hidden field to have it sent automatically when a form is sent, or in something like a meta header (`<meta name="csrftoken" content="...">`), or pretty much any other way.

If it's just plain old form posts, a hidden field is probably the easiest. If javascript is involved (ajax requests), you will probably be better off with one central location in the page (like a meta header) where any javascript can take it from.

Also with forms, you can generate a different token for each new page download, but for ajax-heavy applications changing the token will lead to problems - for most applications, one token per login session is acceptable.

Comment: But my original question is how does the server sends the generated token?

Comment: @KasunDharmadasa I think I answered just that. The server puts the token into generated pages for the client, either in each form, or as one single hidden field, or a JS value, or a meta header, or pretty much any way you can think of. It will be part of the response to a page request.

Comment: what if the server is only serving only static `index.html` file?

Comment: @Rachmaninoff There needs to be some kind of a dynamic component, otherwise it's all static (read only) and you don't need csrf protection. If you're talking about a pure spa with javascript and html served from a cdn, that's a good question, but answer would not fit here, so please post separately.

Comment: @GaborLengyel I exactly mean that, SPA written with AngularJS